# Как сделать текст на изображении более выраженным?

Tags: c#, .net, изображения, bitmap

Пример текста на изображении:

[image: Текст на изображении]

Дана картинка и надо получить другую картинку.
Надо преобразовать уже имеющееся изображение.

Цвета на изображении только черный и белый.

Как сделать этот текст более выраженным (более жирным)?
Какие фильтры или подходы можно применить для такого?

Comment: Т. е. дана картинка и надо получить другую картинку?

Comment: 1.Преобразование Фурье 2.Радон

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, сложновато...

Answer (score 1):

Надо создать объект шрифта и использовать уже его. Так-же можно поиграться с TextRenderingHint, чтоб подобрать нужный режим сглаживания.

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Times New Roman");
Font font = new Font(
   fontFamily,
   32,
   FontStyle.Bold,
   GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255));
string string1 = "SingleBitPerPixel";
string string2 = "AntiAlias";

e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;
e.Graphics.DrawString(string1, font, solidBrush, new PointF(10, 10));

e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
e.Graphics.DrawString(string2, font, solidBrush, new PointF(10, 60));
```

Answer (score 1):

Для каждой точки, не являющейся фоном, закрашиваем 4 (или 8) соседних точек.
Список точек надо получить заранее, чтобы не зациклиться при закрашивании.
При необходимости повторить это несколько раз.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)

Comment: @VladD, да, вроде оно :)